# Easiest way to order array from a string word - Interesting

Tags: arrays, string, actionscript-3

I am writing a childrens game and it consists of letter blocks.

The child has to put the blocks in a correct order (following silhouettes) to spell the word

Now my question is I have 2 Arrays.

```
var myLetters = new Array(
    new BlockC(),
    new BlockA(),
    new BlockB()
);

public static var myLetters2 = new Array(
    new BlockC(),
    new BlockA(),
    new BlockB()
);
```

So you see this is setup to spell the word C A B.

What i would would like to do is have a string variable that i can put the word in to and then have code fill the array in the correct order.

i.e.

var word:String = "CAB";

Hope this makes sense and i can get some good help from you guys

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, here is one way of doing it :

```
var word:String = "CAB";

var letterClassMapping:Object = {
 "C":BlockC,
 "A":BlockA,
 "B":BlockB
};

var myLetters:Array = [];

for(var i:int=0; i<word.length; i++) {
  myLetters.push( new letterClassMapping[word.charAt(i)]() );
}
```

Another way is to use getDefinitionByName to get the class type :

```
var classType:Class = getDefinitionByName("Block" + word.charAt(i)) as Class;
myLetters.push(new classType());
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to need a letter collection with corresponding classes. So, you make yourself an Object of the following srtructure:

```
private static var LETTERS:Object={A:BlockA,B:BlockB,C:BlockC};
```

Then you split your word by single letters (copy one letter out of a word into a new string) and then you can get corresponding class via `LETTERS[letter]`, and a new instance of that class via `new LETTERS[letter]();`

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention they aren't classes they are movie objects

Comment: This doesn't alter a thing. The name "BlockA" is type Class itself, but when you do `new BlockA()` you receive a MovieClip. I have a collection of Monster type objects (classes descendants from one Monster class) and use it like this, having `var m:Monster=new MONSTERS[selectedMonster]();` and it makes me a proper monster.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create toString() functions in Your object and thant join array .

In class create function :

```
public class BlockA {

        public function toString():String {
           return "A";
        }
}
```

And than You can join array items :

```
var arr:Array = [new BlockA , new BlockB , new BlockC];
trace(arr.join(""));
// and compare to Your string:
arr.join("") == word;
```

Comment: toString() and valueOf() are very usefull in similar cases